# Disconnect the Microsoft account from your local user account programmatically via registry or COM?

Tags: windows-8, com, windows-10, user-accounts, microsoft-account

Since Windows 8 (?) the default way of setting up a new a user account is to attach a Microsoft account to the local account.
I'd like to programmatically disconnect that Microsoft account from the local user account, (without losing settings/data) to end up with a traditional clean local account.

I don't have access to WinAPI functions or DLLs, but I can use the COM API access the registry.

So I'm basically just looking for a list of registry entries that I would have to remove or maybe a COM object method that allows me to do it.

Any idea how I could accomplish that?

The programming language I'll be using for that isn't relevant, but since you will ask for it anyway... it's JScript.